# Problem with Firebase authentification - check if user exists by its email address

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created an account on my Firebase, it worked but now I would like to prevent people from creating an account with an email address that already exists. Here is the code:

```
DatabaseManager.shared.userExists(with: email, completion: { [weak self] exists in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }
        guard !exists else {
            strongSelf.alertInvalidEmail()
            print("already exists")
            return
        }
        HapticsManager.shared.vibrate(for: .success)
        self?.presenter(vc, animated: false, pushing: true, completion: nil)
        print("doesnt exist")
    
    })
}
```

This is the alertInvalidEmail function that is called (it works) :

```
@objc private func alertInvalidEmail() {
        myAlert.showAlert(with: "Erreur",
                          message: "Veuillez entrer une adresse e-mail correcte.",
                          on: self)
        HapticsManager.shared.vibrate(for: .warning)
        emailField.text = ""
    }
```

And the extension :

```
final class DatabaseManager {
    
    static let shared = DatabaseManager()
    private let database = Database.database().reference()
    
}

// MARK: - Account Management

extension DatabaseManager {
    
    public func userExists(with email: String,
                           completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {
        
        var safeEmail = email.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "-")
        safeEmail = safeEmail.replacingOccurrences(of: "@", with: "-")
        
        database.child(safeEmail).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            guard snapshot.value as? String != nil else {
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            completion(true)
        })
        
    }
    
    public func insertUser(with user: AppUser) {
        database.child(user.safeEmail).setValue([
            "first_name": user.firstName,
            "last_name": user.lastName
        ])
    }
}


struct AppUser {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let emailAddress: String
    
    var safeEmail: String {
        var safeEmail = emailAddress.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "-")
        safeEmail = safeEmail.replacingOccurrences(of: "@", with: "-")
        return safeEmail
    }    
}
```

And every time I try to register with an email that already exists, its always accepted. Any idea ?
I want to specify that the check for the email address happens in the first view controller, but I only get the password, first name and last name in the following view controllers, it is the reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately "nothing works" isn't a very helpful problem description. See [ask]. Describe what happens, what debugging you have attempted. What should happen. I note that you have haptics and a call to your presenter outside of the completion handler. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Paulw11 The issue is that every time it detects that the email address is not used, even if it already is.

Comment: Set a breakpoint. What is the value of `value` in the snapshot closure? What do you do when the email doesn't exist?  Is it those two lines that are outside the closure?  I am pretty sure you want them in the closure

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated the post, does it helps? Is it because of the value of value ? I don't know I'm still a beginner thank you 

Comment: I still want to know what this line `presenter(vc, animated: false, pushing: true, completion: nil)` does?  Is it your success case?  If so, it is outside of the closure and so it will be called before the firebase operation is complete.

Comment: Also, if you want people to create accounts, Firebase has an authentication system that will manage all of this for you.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes 'presenter' is my success case, it works. But it is always called. Ive put it in the closure now, but it still doesn't work. It prints 'doesnt exist' (Ive updated the post)

Comment: What value do you get for `value`?  Read about the Xcode debugger. It is a very powerful tool that will let you set breakpoints and see exactly what your code is doing.  You can also use the Firestore console to look at the data you have saved.